# «Предположительно» –вводное или таки нет слово?

Tags: запятые

Нужны запятые?

`Я(,) предположительно в среду(,) смогу встретиться.`

`Кто-то – предположительно(,) мистер кот – сломал вазу.`

`Он этого не смог сделать(,) предположительно из-за сломанной ноги.`

`Он этого не смог сделать (предположительно(,) из-за сломанной ноги).`

Comment: You should also ask about commas. The examples are interesting.  http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_625

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лезем в справочник Фрамполь по вводным словам. Там все написано:

> ПРЕДПОЛОЖИТЕЛЬНО, наречие.
>
> 1. Употребляется в функции вводного в модальном   значении «неуверенность, предположение»: Так нежно и ярко  было его сияние,
>    что, будучи, предположительно,   свободным от мира, я пожелал бы
>    бессмертия (А.Грин); По одной  стороне - приемная, кабинет доктора,
>    дальше,   предположительно, столовая и гостиная (В.Набоков);
>    Назначенное,  предположительно, на срок месяца три спустя открытие
>    нового Университета, должно было стать самым   торжественным и широко
>    освещаемым действом (В.Набоков).
> 2. Редко невводное, употребляется в функции   обстоятельства образа действия, произносится тоном уверенности,   убежденности, без паузы
>    перед следующим словом, не   обособляется: У каждой эпохи
>    предположительно существует своя  собственная тональность, и поэзия
>    фиксирует эту   тональность первой (И.Бродский); Никто этого делать не
>    стал,
>
> - возможно, оттого, что каждый склонен к определенной  учтивости при обращении со старым и предположительно  очень пьяным господином
>   (В.Набоков); Цены на картофель  предположительно вырастут на 10
>   рублей.

Сравните со словом **действительно**, которое всегда можно трактовать как **не вводное**

> Слова и сочетания слов, которые в функции вводного  и в другой функции
> имеют одно и то же значение. Даже по  контексту невозможно различить,
> в какой функции употреблено  то или иное слово: все зависит от желания
> автора - либо  подчеркнуть свою субъективность, либо использовать
> слово  в свойственной ему функции. Например: **действительно**

В Словаре подобные слова имеют помету «неустойчиво
вводное».